# How to enable MouseWheel scrolling for a ttk.Frame in a tkinter.Canvas.create_window() widget on Linux?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

**Expected behavior:**
I want to be able to scroll the canvas with a Mousewheel.

**Issue:**
Mousewheel scrolling cease to work when my image is pasted on a `ttk.Label` widget (see **Method 2** of `self.loadImage()`) that is located in `ttk.Frame` that is located in a `tk.Canvas.create_window()` widget. However, Mousewheel scrolling works when my image is pasted on the canvas using method `tk.Canvas.create_image()` (see **Method 1** of `self.loadImage()`). Issue encountered with Python 3.6.5 and Tk.TkVersion 8.6 on Linux.

**Question:** Why does Method 2 not work? How to get it to work?

I have written the following test script to illustrate my issue:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import platform

from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class App(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__( self, parent, *args, **kwargs ):

        super().__init__( parent, style='App.TFrame', borderwidth=10,
                          relief='raised', width=390, height=390 )
        self.style = None
        self.vscrollbar = None
        self.canvas = None
        self.canvas_window = None
        self.interior = None

        self.setStyle()
        self.createWidgets()
        self.loadImage()
        self.createBinding()

        self.rowconfigure( 0, weight=1 )
        self.columnconfigure( 0, weight=1 )


    def setStyle(self):
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.configure( 'App.TFrame', background='pink' )
        self.style.configure( 'interior.TFrame', background='red' )


    def createWidgets(self):
        self.vscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical')
        self.vscrollbar.pack( side='right', fill='y', expand='false' )

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas( self,
                                 bd=0, #no border
                                 highlightthickness=0, #no focus highlight
                                 yscrollcommand=self.vscrollbar.set,#use self.vscrollbar
                                 background='blue', #improves resizing appearance
                               )
        self.canvas.pack( side='left', fill='both', expand='true' )
        self.vscrollbar.config( command=self.canvas.yview )

        self.canvas.xview_moveto( 0 )
        self.canvas.yview_moveto( 0 )

        self.interior = ttk.Frame( self.canvas,
                                   style='interior.TFrame',
                                   borderwidth=10,
                                   relief=tk.SUNKEN )

        self.canvas_window = self.canvas.create_window(
            0, 0, window=self.interior, anchor='nw' )


    def loadImage(self):
        image = './test_image.png'
        image = Image.open(image)
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        width, height = image.size
        print(width, height)
        self.canvas.config( scrollregion=(0, 0, width, height) )

        #Method 1
        #self.canvas_obj_id = self.canvas.create_image( 0, 0, image=self.image,
        #                                               anchor=tk.NW )

        #Method 2
        self.label = ttk.Label(self.interior, image=self.image )
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')


    def createBinding(self):
        if platform.system() == 'Linux':
            self.canvas.bind('<Button-4>', self._on_mousewheel_linux)
            self.canvas.bind('<Button-5>', self._on_mousewheel_linux)
            print('Binded <Button-4> and <Button-5>')
        elif platform.system() == 'Windows':
            self.canvas.bind('<MouseWheel>', self._on_mousewheel_windows)


    def _on_mousewheel_linux(self, event):
        if event.num == 4: self.canvas.yview_scroll( -1, "units" )
        if event.num == 5: self.canvas.yview_scroll(  1, "units" )


    def _on_mousewheel_windows(self, event):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll( int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units" )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App( root )
    app.grid( row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew' )
    root.rowconfigure( 0, weight=1 )
    root.columnconfigure( 0, weight=1 )

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This works fine on windows if you correct the if statement and convert the number to an integer. I know you are looking for a fix for linux but there was a problem with your code for windows portion.

Comment: It should be `int(-1*int(event.delta/120))`. At least in my version if you `-1*int(event.delta/120)` it converts to a float and not an integer so to correct this you can run `int` on it again after the math is complete.

Comment: @Mike-SMT will `int(-1*(event.delta/120))` work for you? I think the other `int()` isn't necessary.

Comment: Probably. I see no reason for it to not work. The 2nd inner int() is likely redundant.

Comment: Can any Linux tkinter user can advice me if Method 2 works on your system or point out the mistake in my script?  Greatly appreciate.